# How to get value from position in onSuggestionClick(int position) in android

Tags: android

I want to get value from the position parameter in onSuggestionClick(int position). Corresponding to each selection, a position is passed in the method. How can I obtain the string value from the position?

The method is:

```
 public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position)
            {
                // Your code here
            String selectedItem = (String)mAdapter.getItem(position);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext()," on suggestion click position and item is" + position + selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SearchResultsActivity.class));

                return true;
            }
```

The corresponding adapter is :

```
final String[] from = new String[] {"cityName"};
        final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                null,
                from,
                to,
                CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        search.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I am getting following error:

> java.io.IOException
>               at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException

Answer (score 1):

**position** parameter returns the absolute position of the clicked item in the list of displayed suggestions.

`mAdapter` is a object of `SimpleCursorAdapter`

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
```

Below code is to get the text value of clicked suggestion

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mAdapter);
searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
        Cursor cursor = mAdapter.getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition( position );
        columnIndex = 1 /* Set your column index*/
        String selectedItem = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        Log.d("Clicked Item", selectedItem);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
        /* Write your code */
        return true;
    }
});
```

Logcat:
[image: LogCat Print]

Search UI:
[image: Search UI]